# Eliminar líneas con cantidad y precios iguales con signos diferentes

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql, transact-sql

En SQL 2019 tengo la siguiente tabla con entradas o compras de artículos y devoluciones

```
DECLARE @Diario TABLE(Id INT IDENTITY, Fecha DATE, Articulo varchar(30),Tipo_ES INT, TipoMovimiento int, Cantidad INT, Precio NUMERIC(8, 2),Contador int);
INSERT INTO @Diario (Fecha,Articulo,Tipo_ES,TipoMovimiento,Cantidad,Precio,Contador)
VALUES 
('2023-09-05','10120100',0,20,252,34.21,389238)
,('2023-09-05','10120100',0,20,252,34.21,389244)
,('2023-09-05','10120100',0,20,-252,34.21,389249)
,('2023-09-05','10120100',0,21,-252,34.21,391302)
,('2023-09-05','10120100',0,21,252,37.91,391303)
,('2023-09-18','10120100',0,20,56,34.40,390696)
,('2023-09-18','10120100',0,20,84,34.40,390738)
,('2023-09-18','10120100',0,21,-56,34.40,391242)
,('2023-09-18','10120100',0,21,56,37.98,391243)
,('2023-09-18','10120100',0,21,-84,34.40,391252)
,('2023-09-18','10120100',0,21,84,37.98,391253)
,('2023-10-20','10120100',0,20,310,35.08,396280)
,('2023-10-20','10120100',0,21,-310,35.08,398152)
,('2023-10-20','10120100',0,21,310,38.27,398153)

SELECT * FROM @Diario  ORDER BY Fecha, Tipo_ES, Contador;
```

necesito eliminar las líneas que tienen una cantidad igual y un precio negativo y otro positivo en este caso las líneas de la 1 a la 4, de la 6 a las 8,la 10 y desde la 12 a la 13, el resultado debe de ser este

```
DELETE @diario

INSERT INTO @Diario (Fecha,Articulo,Tipo_ES,TipoMovimiento,Cantidad,Precio,Contador)
VALUES 
('2023-09-05','10120100',0,21,252,37.91,391303)
,('2023-09-18','10120100',0,21,56,37.98,391243)
,('2023-09-18','10120100',0,21,84,37.98,391253)
,('2023-10-20','10120100',0,21,310,38.27,398153)

SELECT * FROM @Diario  ORDER BY Fecha, Tipo_ES, Contador;
```

si pongo todas la variantes que he usado llenaría esto de código innecesario. ¿ me ayudáis ?, gracias

Comment: Dudo mucho que puedas hacer esto con una consulta...  no tiene un seguimiento logico para un sql, deberias probar con alguna clase de procedimiento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Primer intento

Si entendí bien y quieres eliminar aquellas filas "duplicadas" con el mismo precio y valor abosuluto de la cantidad, entonces puedes hacer un subquery con la cual utilizando las funciones ventana (window functions) pongas un 1 en una nueva columna ("borrar") en las filas que hay que eliminar (las "duplicadas"), y luego eliminar dichas filas (las que tienen un 1 en la columna borrar) con una sentencia DELETE :

```
WITH sq AS (
  SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN lag(precio) OVER (Partition by Precio, abs(Cantidad) order by Precio asc, Cantidad desc) 
       IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS borrar
FROM @Diario)
  
DELETE FROM sq WHERE borrar = 1;
```

Según los datos del ejemplo, este sería el resultado:

| Id | Fecha | Articulo | Tipo_ES | TipoMovimiento | Cantidad | Precio | Contador |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-09-05 | 10120100 | 0 | 20 | 252 | 34.21 | 389238 |
| 5 | 2023-09-05 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 252 | 37.91 | 391303 |
| 6 | 2023-09-18 | 10120100 | 0 | 20 | 56 | 34.40 | 390696 |
| 7 | 2023-09-18 | 10120100 | 0 | 20 | 84 | 34.40 | 390738 |
| 9 | 2023-09-18 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 56 | 37.98 | 391243 |
| 11 | 2023-09-18 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 84 | 37.98 | 391253 |
| 12 | 2023-10-20 | 10120100 | 0 | 20 | 310 | 35.08 | 396280 |
| 14 | 2023-10-20 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 310 | 38.27 | 398153 |

## Segundo intento

No está claro el enunciado. Lo que deducí del ejemplo es que quieres agrupar por el valor absoluto de la cantidad, y luego ordenar por el precio (descendente); eliminado todas las filas que tienen el mismo valor absoluto de la cantidad, excepto la de mayor precio (para cada grupo). En dicho la caso la query sería la siguiente (es similar a la anterior, pero ahora no agrupo por el precio):

```
WITH sq AS (
select *,
    CASE WHEN lag(precio) OVER (Partition by abs(Cantidad) order by Precio desc) 
       is null THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS borrar
from @Diario)
  
DELETE FROM sq WHERE borrar = 1;
```

El resultado sería:

| Id | Fecha | Articulo | Tipo_ES | TipoMovimiento | Cantidad | Precio | Contador |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2023-09-05 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 252 | 37.91 | 391303 |
| 9 | 2023-09-18 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 56 | 37.98 | 391243 |
| 11 | 2023-09-18 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 84 | 37.98 | 391253 |
| 14 | 2023-10-20 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 310 | 38.27 | 398153 |

## Tercer intento

Teniendo en cuenta que el siguiente enunciado describe mejor el requerimiento, a partir del mismo preparé una nueva solución.

**Requerimiento**: "Eliminar las parejas de filas en las cuales coincide el precio y la cantidad, pero la cantidad es del del signo contrario, dejando solo las filas que no tienen pareja según dicho criterio."

Tengo que hacer una aclaración: mi query no solo borrara pares de filas, si hay mas de una (dos, tres, cuatro, cinco, etc) filas que tienen el mismo precio y valor absoluto de la cantidad también serán borradas. Solo quedarán aquellas filas que no tiene pareja (con el mismo precio y valor absoluto de la cantidad).

```
WITH sq AS (
  SELECT abs(Cantidad) AS Cantidad, Precio, count(*) AS CantidadFilas
  FROM @Diario
  GROUP BY abs(Cantidad), Precio)
  
DELETE d
FROM @Diario d
INNER JOIN sq ON sq.Cantidad = abs(d.Cantidad) and sq.Precio = d.Precio
WHERE sq.CantidadFilas > 1;
```

Según los datos de ejemplo quedarían solo las siguientes filas:

| Id | Fecha | Articulo | Tipo_ES | TipoMovimiento | Cantidad | Precio | Contador |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2023-09-05 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 252 | 37.91 | 391303 |
| 9 | 2023-09-18 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 56 | 37.98 | 391243 |
| 11 | 2023-09-18 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 84 | 37.98 | 391253 |
| 14 | 2023-10-20 | 10120100 | 0 | 21 | 310 | 38.27 | 398153 |

Comment: primero que todo muchas gracias nachospiu. Las líneas 1,6,7,12 también deben de ser eliminadas pues por ejemplo para la cantidad 252 y precio 34.21 hay 4 líneas, dos positivas y dos negativas por lo que solo debía de quedar la quinta que es 252 y precio  37.91. Si te fijas siempre la cantidad de líneas es impar así por ejemplo hay 3 líneas con cantidad 84, una negativa y otra positiva con precio 34.40 y la tercera con precio 37.98 que es la que debe de quedar

Comment: De nada @pfigueredo. No me termina de quedar claro el enunciado. Subí una nueva query, pero no estoy seguro de que sea lo que necesitas. Si la query es correcta, deberías agregar otra columna para ordenar, porque si hubiera dos filas con las misma cantidad y precio, eliminaría cualquier de ellas aleatoriamente (quizás podrías utilizar el ID).

Comment: otra vez gracias @nachospiu, lo probaré y te comentaré. Igual no me he explicado bien. Siempre serán un numero impar de precios y cantidades de los cuales 1 par ó 2 ó n pares tendrán una cantidad positiva y una negativa iguales en términos absolutos con el mismo precio, estas deben de ser eliminadas, solo quedaría una línea con precio mayor o menor que los anteriores. Por ejemplo: 5 valores que son 2 de 252 con precio 34.21, otros dos negativos -252 con el mismo precio 34.21 y al final debe de quedar la línea quinta con 252 y precio 37.91 que puede ser mayor o menor que los anteriores

Comment: Entonces mi query no te va a servir. Según lo que entendí de tu última explicación el enunciado debería ser "Eliminar las parejas de filas en las cuales coincide el precio y la cantidad, pero la cantidad es del del signo contrario, dejando solo las filas que no tienen pareja según dicho criterio". ¿No se si es correcto?

Comment: Me has entendido perfectamente y has captado a la perfección la idea pero he probado poner un precio menor en una de las líneas "huérfana" o "sin pareja" y no se queda esta última por ser el orden del precio en la partición descendente. Pero me sirve perfecto porque al parecer esa línea "sin pareja" o "huérfana" siempre tendrá un precio mayor así que otra vez gracias y quedo muy agradecido, saludos

Comment: Por eso te comentaba que mi query no te iba a servir (solo funciona si el precio es mayor). Ahora que comprendí mejor el problema voy a agregar un nuevo intento de solución.